# Batch processing in Mule using splitter component

Tags: mule

How can I process xml as batch in Mule using splitter component.

I have an xml,

```
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <b>2</b>
  <b>3</b>
  <b>4</b>
  <b>5</b>
  <b>6</b>
</a>
```

In litter I gave the splitting logic as `//b`

`6` concurrent request is processed.

But I want in `Batch`, and batch should process `two` elements. So that 3 concurrent request will be processed.

How can I do this in Mule and what Xpath I should use for this ?

I knew I can use `ForEach` with batch. But I want to make it as concurrent.

Answer (score 0):

What batch expects is a collection. If you use splitter what you are going to generate is a number of different messages, that will confuse batch.

An expression transformer, with an `xpath()` or `xpath3()` function with the expression `//b` should do the trick.

Comment: But how `//b` will do the batch. I want 2 `b` process at a time. Where do I specify the batch number.

Comment: for the sake of clarity, when you say batch do you mean http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Batch+Processing ?